# Deploying SailsJS to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js

I can't make my app to start, it keeps failing with following error:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

I created `application.js` file within `config` folder, with following content:

```
module.exports = {
  port: process.env.PORT || 1337
};
```

but that didn't help.

Structure of my app is following.
I have two separate applications on Heroku. They both have exact same code, except different Procfiles (so that I can start different scripts).
First app is my actual application, and second one is worker that should fill database.
First Procfile has following content:

`web: NODE_ENV=production node app.js`

And the second (worker) one:

`web: NODE_ENV=production node worker/APIDataLoader.js`

The worker app is the one that is failing.

Could it be that something else is wrong, and that this error actually 'masks' it?

**UPDATE**

I change my second Procfile to this:

```
worker: NODE_ENV=production node worker/APIDataLoader.js
```

so now it is worker. I also run `heroku ps:scale worker=1` for this application.
This is what I get now:

```
State changed from up to starting
2014-06-12T14:42:53.556701+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `NODE_ENV=production node worker/APIDataLoader.js`
2014-06-12T14:42:54.407140+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-06-12T14:42:52.111153+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-06-12T14:42:54.518997+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-06-12T14:51:54.297431+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=surge-gearstream-worker.herokuapp.com request_id=073599af-192b-4b23-aef1-be7a264c43d2 fwd="188.2.72.207" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-12T14:51:54.508784+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=surge-gearstream-worker.herokuapp.com request_id=adbb0bfa-2df7-47ad-9a27-4f6823db6ecf fwd="188.2.72.207" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Is it possible to run only worker?

Answer (score 2):

Several problems here, and rules / best-practices you should conform to:

1. Do not separate web/worker into separate applications, have them both in the same app, in the same `Procfile`:

   ```
   web: node app.js
   worker: node worker/APIDataLoader.js
   ```
2. The `NODE_ENV` environment var belongs in the `heroku config`, and not to be passed in the `Procfile`
3. Your worker seems to simply exit with nothing to do, is some error being suppressed?
4. A `web` process is not required in the `Procfile`, make sure you are not trying to scale `web` to more than `0`.

Comment: hey YuvalAdam, thanks for reply. I did as you suggested. Deployed one app, and changed Procfile, set NODE_ENV. I'm not sure what you mean by 4. statement? When I log to Heroku, I see this http://dropsha.re/#FNI4of8. However, in Heroku logs, I still receive same error, 'No web processes running'.